# For a compact operator $T \in K(X, H)$ and H an Hilbert space, $\overline{T(X)}$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let X be a normed space, H be a Hilbert space, and let $T \in K(X, H)$ the set of compact operators. Show that T(X) is separable. I tried to use the fact that the set of finite rank operators $F(X,H) = K(X,H)$ when H is an Hilbert space, to show that $T(x)$ is countable (since we need to show that $\overline{T(X)}$ is separable, that is, that it contains a countable dense subset)

Comment: This just follows from the fact that every compact metric space is separable, no?

Comment: Of course $T(X)$ need not be countable.  But if you show $T(X)$ has a countable dense set, then it follows that its closure also has a countable dense set.

Answer (score 1):

$T(\{x:\|x||\leq 1\})$ has a countable dense set $(h_n)$ (because this set is relatively compact). Show that $\{kh_n: k \in \mathbb N, n\geq 1\}$ is a  countable dense set in $\overline {T(X)}$.

Details: Let $y \in \overline {T(X)}$ and $\epsilon >0$ Choose $z \in T(X)$ such that $\|y-z\| <\epsilon /2$. Write $z$ as $Tx$. Choose $N$ such that $\|\frac x  N\| <1$.  Let $x_0=\frac x  N$ . Then $Tx_0 \in T(\{x:\|x||\leq 1\})$. So there exists $k$ such that $\|Tx_0-h_k\| <\epsilon /2N$.  Also, $\|y-Nh_k\|\leq \|y-z\|+\|z-Nh_k\| =\|y-z\|+N\|Tx_0-h_k\|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Explain why $T(\{x:\|x||\leq 1\})$ has a countable dense set.

Comment: I agree that ${T(\{x:∥x||≤1\})} $ has a countable dense subset ( here is the proof : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414350/showing-a-compact-metric-space-has-a-countable-dense-subset)

Comment: @wainwain I have given a very detailed proof. Let me know if you need even more details.